# How do I read a local Markdown file in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, fs

I am using a library called `react-markdown`. If you know React, it's implementation is very simple.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';

var content = '# This is a header\n\nAnd this is a paragraph';

ReactDOM.render(
  <ReactMarkdown source={content} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The demo for the library only discusses creating the Markdown string as a variable, not an locally located file. The obvious thing to me to do was to use `fs` in Node. So I wrote the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import content from './content/generic.md';

fs.readFile(content, (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

Before I can provide the `ReactMarkdown` element with content, Webpack complains that `readFile` is not a function!

Specifically, it highlights the `fs.readFile` line and says:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_fs___default.a.readFile is not a function
```

This same error occurs if I use `import {readFile } from 'fs'` and it also occurs when I use fs.stat or fs.open. Isn't fs a default library for node? Should it be included in package.json for the webpack? Even if I run `npm install --save fs` I still can't access these functions. (P.S. I am using create-react-app)

Moreover, if I can't do this with `fs`, is there another method?

Comment: Thanks, Andrew—both for the correct answer and the edits. I guess I still need to build a promise so that the React element doesn't try to render until fs.readFile is done, because right now, even though your answer works, I still get a message from React that `content` is `undefined`

Comment: You could use `readFile` and set a callback (as the third argument) to set state once the file is read. That way it will rerender the component once the file is done being read.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `fs` module does not have a default export, and so importing it with default import syntax won't work. The `fs` module only exports named exports, so import all of them under the name `fs` like so:

```
import * as fs from 'fs'
```

This will import all the named exports as properties of one object named `fs`. That will allow you to do `fs.readFile`. Better yet, you could use named export importing to import *just* the function you need:

```
import { readFile } from 'fs'
```

Secondly, pass `readFile` a *path* to the Markdown file, don't import it directly with import syntax:

```
fs.readFile('./content/generic.md', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    ...
});
```

Unless you have the correct loader to import the file, do not import it with `require` or `import`. Node will treat it as a JavaScript file and try to interpret the Markdown as JavaScript. Pass the path of the Markdown file directly to `readFile`. Also make sure to specify the encoding as `utf8` to get the string content of the file.

Comment: Well... quid pro quo... everything you said made sense to me, and I thought it worked once, but I am now back to getting the same error. If I use `import {readFile} from 'fs'` then it says readFile is not a function. If I use `import * as fs from 'fs'` I get the original error `fs__.readFile is not a function` I even used `npm install --save fs`—which you shouldn't have to—and still nothing. One odd thing of note is that the terminal puts "Compiled Successfully"—it's Chrome that's registering the errors.

Comment: @russellmania It depends on where you run your code. The browser can't access the file system, and the `fs` module only works in a Node environment. It doesn't exist outside of Node. If you're bundling for the web, maybe look into the [`browserify-fs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-fs) package. It's the same exact code but with `browserify-fs` as the package name and it's compatible with the web.

Comment: @russellmania So, even in a node environment, `fs` isn't working?

Comment: I see what you're saying. Really, I guess what I want is to include the external markdown file inside of the production bundle that comes out of webpack and then give React-markdown access to that file, which makes that an ajax call, I suppose.

Comment: @russellmania If you're using `browserify-fs`, it uses the [`level-filesystem`](https://github.com/mafintosh/level-filesystem/blob/master/README.md) package which does NOT support `fs.read`, `fs.open`, nor `fs.stat`. To use all of `fs` you *need* to be in the Node environment because the browser can't access the filesystem.